# How do I keep the pupils black?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders

I'm still trying to understand nodes. But I have looked everywhere for explanations on proper eye gloss/transparency and have followed all instructions to the letter, always to the same effect. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. When I add the glossy toon shader, the eye becomes milky. I love the effect, but I need the pupils to stay black. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J0umYchSbfx2weOFbjVrUlinVBsLDAPC
[image]

Comment: try to be more specific and detailed, maybe show just eyes and their materials settings, and/or upload a model (use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/then paste the provided link in your question text)